# Is it possible for a `div` to act like an HTML anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, onclick

I'd like a way to have a block-level HTML tag act like an `<a>` tag.

I've been using React and React-Router for a while now and tend to use `<div>` for a lot of components. Because I wrapping an anchor tag in a block-level tag such as `<div>` isn't valid HTML, I can't add browser-known links in my apps.

One idea I had is to write all my components as a `<span>`. Sadly, this isn't the solution I want since I also don't control the HTML 3rd party components.

How would I make it so a `div` or any other block-level tag, act like an anchor tag where hovering shows a link in the bottom of the browser, [CTRL][LEFT_CLICK] and [MIDDLE_CLICK] open a new tab, and a single click changes the route?

A React solution isn't required.

Comment: "wrapping an anchor tag in a block-level tag such as <div> isn't valid HTML" untrue. <a> elements can contain divs as of HTML5.

Comment: I guess you're right: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct

Comment: Could you not wrap the contents of the div within the a tag?

Comment: No. Based on how I need things to be linkable, it requires wrapping larger groupings of elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `<a>` instead of `<div>` if those requirements are necessary.

While this wasn't the case in the past, HTML5 allows you to wrap anchor tags around block-level elements:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1828032/1624862

There are still limitations though. If you wrap your `<a>` in a `<span>`, then you have to have inline elements inside. Block-level elements are only allowed inside `<a>` when it's also wrapped in a block-level element.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two ways of doing it

**Use little JavaScript**

`<div onclick="location.href='http://www.thelink.com';" style="cursor:pointer;"></div>`

**Make `<a>` act like a div**

```
a {
    display: block;
}
```

You can set other stuff say height and width.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Using `onclick` like that doesn't solve the issue. The browser just treats it at as a normal `div` with a pointer on hover. None of the requirements I require are satisfied.

Comment: Making `a` act like a `div` is fine, but it's not valid HTML to put block-level elements inside an anchor. There's no way to ensure it will actually work like I'd expect in various browsers on various devices.

Comment: inline js should be avoided, it's a bad practice that leads to hard-to-maintain code

Answer (score 0):

You can't wrap anchor tag around div but can do vice versa won't that help.

Link

Please take a look at below code sandbox link.
https://codesandbox.io/s/9z5y52mk8w